# Converting a decimal to binary in C

Tags: c, binary, hex

Edit: Sorry for the weird format, I'm still new to Stackoverflow but here is the actual main method that is supposed to be printing out the conversions. I've left out the hexadecimal part in the main method because that already works and there would be an error about there being too much code and not enough details. Again, I appreciate all of the help!

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print_binary( FILE* out, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[]);
void print_hex( FILE* out, uint8_t hex[]);
void print_hex_compact( FILE* out, uint8_t hex[]);

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 3 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s <input file> <output file>\n", argv[0] );
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE* in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    FILE* out = fopen(argv[2], "w");

    fprintf( out, "%20s%20s\n", "Input","Converted");

    uint64_t number;
    fscanf( in, "%" SCNu64, &number );
    enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[64];
    uint8_t hex[16];
    while( !feof( in ) )
    {
        fprintf( out, "%20" PRIu64 "\t", number );
        convert_to_binary( number, bits );
        print_binary(out, bits);
        convert_to_hexadecimal(number, hex );
        fprintf( out, "%20" PRIu64 "\t", number );
        print_hex_compact(out, hex);
        fscanf( in, "%" SCNu64, &number );
    }


    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);

    return 0;
}

void print_binary( FILE* out, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[])
{
    for ( int i=63; i>=0; i-- )
    {
        if ( bits[i] == ZERO )
            fprintf(out, "0");
        else
            fprintf(out, "1");

        if ( i % 4 == 0 ) fprintf(out, " ");
    }
    fprintf(out, "\n");
}
```

I've been struggling with this problem for quite some time now. The main function and the convert header file are already given and not allowed to be modified, instead a convert.c function is to be created with "void convert_to_binary(uint64_t number, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[])" and "void convert_to_hexadecimal(uint64_t number, uint8_t hex[])".

As far as the hexadecimal part goes, I've figured it out and it prints out the correct value with "

```
void convert_to_hexadecimal(uint64_t number, uint8_t hex[]) {
      for (int i = 15; i >= 0; i--) {
        uint8_t digit = (number >> (i * 4)) & 0xF;

        // Store the hexadecimal digit in the array.
        hex[i] = digit;
    }
}
```

but with my current binary code of "

```
void convert_to_binary(uint64_t number, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[]) {
      for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
        bits[i] = (enum ZERO_OR_ONE)((number >> i) & 1);
    }
}
```

" I receive the output

```
1011 0010 1100 0111 1011 1000
```

for "5564275972427363982" instead of

```
0100 1101 0011 1000 0100 0111
```

Could someone help me with this and explain what I'm doing wrong with my code?

I've tried to change my code multiple times, trying to change the i from 63 to 64 etc. but nothing has seemed to work so far.

Comment: You've not shown the code that prints the output, either hex or binary... Perhaps the problem is there... (24 bits looks to be too few when you're displaying a 64 bit value...)

Comment: Hi! The code that prints the output isn't allowed to be modified because it was already given by the professor so I figured that I probably should not include it

Comment: If one ignores the truncation, your code looks to be correct. However, the shown problem seems to be that each output bit is the opposite of what is expected... The symptoms point to the (unknown) code doing the printing being incorrect...

Comment: 5564275972427363982 in base 2 is 0100110100111000010001111000010000100000110001100011011010001110, why are you expecting 010011010011100001000111? Your code should work, or at least it works for me using an array of chars: https://ideone.com/sVOaPb

Comment: `void print_binary( FILE* out, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[])
{
 for ( int i=63; i>=0; i-- )
 {
  if ( bits[i] == ZERO )
   fprintf(out, "0");
  else
   fprintf(out, "1");

  if ( i % 4 == 0 ) fprintf(out, " ");
 }
 fprintf(out, "\n");
}` this is the print binary function that is supposed to be printing out the conversion; however, when testing for differences with the given input and output files/values, this ends up being the result: 
 5564275972427363982    1011 0010 1100 0111 1011 1000        |        5564275972427363982       0100 1101 0011 1000 0100 0111

Comment: Hi! Please edit the question to include that detail!

Comment: We'll need to see the `#define ZERO  ???? "`, too...

Comment: Thank you! I believe it's been fully updated now

Comment: We still don't know what the prof's `enum ZERO_OR_ONE` looks like.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, aside from that, "enum ZERO_OR_ONE { ONE, ZERO };

/**
 * number is the number to be converted
 * bits is an array of 64 elements of the enumerated type
 */ 
void convert_to_binary( uint64_t number, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[] );
/**
 * number is the number to be converted
 * hex is an array of 16 elements 
 */ 
void convert_to_hexadecimal( uint64_t number, uint8_t hex[] );" this is all I have been given

Comment: There it is: `enum ZERO_OR_ONE { ONE, ZERO };` The conventional expectation of `0` followed by `1` has been swapped... Your binary code is doing the right thing (to 99.99% of the world), but the prof is tricking you to assign the _token_, not the value of each bit... I'd drop that course, asap... Apart from making you aware that "assumptions can lead to bugs", this is crap from the prof...

Comment: @Fe2O3 nice catch! This should be an answer.

Comment: Given that "1 means 0 and 0 means 1", the prof has departed from this stupidity in order to use "convention" when printing the hex values. Tell the prof, on my behalf, his hexadecimal printing function is _obviously_ back-to-front...

Comment: Unfortunately, I really need the class to graduate and it's only taught by this one professor :/

Comment: Actually, this is good training for the workplace... You're bound to meet a **lot** of managers and others in the upper echelon who also have their head up their .... Good luck with the course and exams... :-)

Answer (score 1):

`enum ZERO_OR_ONE { ONE, ZERO }`

"*To assume makes an ass of u and me*"...

Your code converting to binary is correct by conventional standards.

The *trick* to solving this problem is to recognise that the supplied definitions **reverse** the conventional meaning of the tokens `ZERO` and `ONE`. Apart from the lesson to be learnt expressed by the quotation above, this is a great way to waste a student's limited time.

Seeing that the binary values of 0/1 are swapped, the following would be fixed code:

```
bits[i] = !(enum ZERO_OR_ONE)((number >> i) & 1);
//        ^--- notice the inversion
```

Given that the prof could have used the power of `enum` to really make your life difficult:

```
enum ZERO_OR_ONE { ONE = 54, ZERO = 42 };
```

you need to play by those rules:

```
bits[i] = ((number >> i) & 1) ? ONE : ZERO;
```

Lesson learnt...

(You could ask the prof "In your print function, why does `ZERO` output `"0"` but **any other value** means `1` ?")

Answer (score 0):

1. You have far not enough digits. The result is: `0100 1101 0011 1000 0100 0111 1000 0100 0010 0000 1100 0110 0011 0110 1000 1110`

```
enum ZERO_OR_ONE
{
    ZERO, ONE,
};

void convert_to_binary(uint64_t number, enum ZERO_OR_ONE bits[])
{
    for(uint64_t mask = 1ULL << 63; mask; mask >>= 1)
    {
        if(number & mask) *bits = ONE;
        else *bits = ZERO;
        bits++;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    enum ZERO_OR_ONE arr[64];

    convert_to_binary(5564275972427363982ULL, arr);

    for(int x = 0; x< 64; x++) printf("%d%s", arr[x], x % 4 == 3 ? " " : "");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/89bWYcj71

Comment: How is this supposed to help the OP with _their_ problem?